# Fail to update QGIS on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, qgis

I'm trying to update QGIS on Ubuntu 18.4, but I am not able to do it.

I following the [instruction](https://qgis.org/zh-Hans/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) to install the latest version of QGIS, I got the following errors.

```html
XXXX@XXXX:~$ sudo apt-get install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qgis : Depends: libqgis-3d3.14.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-analysis3.14.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-app3.14.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-core3.14.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libqgis-gui3.14.0 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python3-qgis (= 1:3.14.0+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: qgis-providers (= 1:3.14.0+28bionic) but it is not going to be installed
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.14.0+28bionic) but 3.10.4+dfsg-1~bionic1 is to be installed
                     Depends: grass740
                     Depends: libgdal20 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-app3.14.0 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-core3.14.0 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgis-gui3.14.0 but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libqgisgrass7-3.14.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why. That error message is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your question so that it is both readable and searchable. The image you've posted is useless to people who are reading the site on a mobile device or a screen reader or who are behind a proxy that blocks imgur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with ubuntugis-unstable version repository (https://qgis.org/ubuntugis)?

```
sudo apt-get install gnupg software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 51F523511C7028C3
sudo add-apt-repository "deb     https://qgis.org/ubuntugis `lsb_release -c -s` main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```